# Capture Java process Jmap output

Tags: java

I am running a Java process and simultaneously I am trying to capture the heap size information of the spawned Java process using Java's **Jmap** utility `jmap.exe`.

I am unable to capture the output information provided by **Jmap**.

Can anyone help me How to Capture the jamp command output to a file after the debugger is attached to process successfully?

My command looks like this: `jmap.exe -heap processid`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *catch* the heap information, you have to use `-dump` option.

> -dump:[live,]format=b,file=filename
>
> Dumps the Java heap in hprof binary format to filename. The live suboption is optional. If specified, only the live objects in the heap are dumped. To browse the heap dump, you can use jhat (Java Heap Analysis Tool) to read the generated file.

Then, you can use `jhat` command to analyze the dump.

Comment: Thank you. I want to validate the heap information in that case how to read the dump file as it will be non readable format. How jhat helps in reading the specified content say max and min heap size.

Comment: `jhat` starts a local web server to present heap analysis, then you can see histogram to get that info. But maybe Eclipse MAT is a more easy and straightforward tool for you.